# how to do scala play forms validation for a field with different errors

Tags: scala, validation, playframework, playframework-2.4

I am trying to add some validation to our form for a field.  It is the first .verifying below.  At the moment even if it fails the new validation it then goes to check the rest of the .verifying and returns several error messages.
If the field fails my new validation I would like it to not do all the other verifying and just return.  So basically if my field matches the regex for a temporary field, I want it to return an error message without continuing the rest of the validation.

```
val form = Form(
mapping(
  "my_field" -> text
    .verifying(Messages("error.field.temporary"), x => x.matches(TEMP_FIELD))
    .verifying(Messages("error.mandatory", Messages("field")), _.length > 0)
    .verifying(Messages("error.field.invalid"), x => x.length == 0 || MyField.isValid(x.toUpperCase()))
    .verifying(Messages("error.field.invalid"), x => !MyField.isValid(x.toUpperCase()) || x.takeRight(1).toUpperCase().matches(FIELD_SUFFIX_REGEX))))
(MemberDetails.apply)(MemberDetails.unapply))
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What's the downside to performing the additional verifications?  Are there significant costs incurred from the `MyField.isValid` method?

Comment: no, but you get more than 1 error message when you should only get one.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this by using a constraint.  Good information is available here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaCustomValidations